# VB Script open secure web page programmatically

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I'm writing a VB Script code, as part of cimplicity object. The code basically need to open IE with a specific URL and autologin to the webpage. The login is a "windows security" popup window. Can i log in to it pragmatically?
[image]

Here is a part of my code:

```
On Error GoTo ERR_TRP
Dim IE
Dim UID As CimObjectVariable
Dim PWD As CimObjectVariable
Dim URL As CimObjectVariable

Dim sUID As String
Dim sPWD As String
Dim sURL As String

Set UID = CimGetScriptOwner().GetVariable("USER")
Set PWD = CimGetScriptOwner().GetVariable("PWD")
Set URL = CimGetScriptOwner().GetVariable("IP")
sUID = UID.Value
sPWD = PWD.Value
sURL = URL.Value
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.navigate sURL
Sleep(1000)

Err_Trp:
    x = MSGBOX ("Cannot open the camera Please check User-Password-IP", 0 , "Eror")
```

Comment: `Dim ... As` won't work in VBS, all variables in VBS has Variant type. Just use `Dim` without `As`. Could you share the URL which gives you such popup window (or any similar)?

Comment: Sorry, i can't share it. This is company's internal URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as omegastripes wrote, you can't declare variable data-types in VBS, however to send the username/password to the popup login window after navigating to the page use this code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Windows Security"
WshShell.SendKeys "YourUserID"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}" 
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "YourPassword"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Just one question, how can i bring the IE page on top of my application?

Comment: `WshShell.AppActivate IE.Name`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another question: can i ask "if the windows security is activated then perform the login"? Because not for all of the URLs there is a log in